# JS/PHP: Wont alert error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
  $("#continue").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "dbc.php?check=First",
    data: {full_name : $('#full_name').val(),
         usr_email : $('#usr_email').val()},

       success: function(msg){
            if(msg==1){
              $("#First_1").hide();
              $("#Next_2").toggle(); 
           }else{
              alert(msg);
           }         
        }
     });
     return false;
  });
}); 
    </script>
```

Here's dbc.php?check=First [phpbin.net/x/249121011](http://phpbin.net/x/249121011)

if it´s receiving echo 1; from dbc.php?check=First, then hide & toggle, else then alert the output error.

Please check the link for the php, what is wrong here?

Right now i just get an empty alert.

Comment: What does the PHP script return, exactly?  This will help you determine if it's a JS bug or a PHP bug.

Comment: Array in a alert, i think its the $err[] i did wrong? no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['check']` is never set, thus your code isn't being called, thus nothing is output.  Either remove the check for `$_POST['check']` in your PHP script, add `check: 'First'` to the `data` property to the `$.ajax` call, or change `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Comment: Now i get a alert message that says "Array"

Comment: @Karem, Nothing in your code indicates that anything except `1` or nothing (or a PHP notice/warning/error) can be printed.  If you post more of your code, maybe we can find the source of your other problem.

Comment: please check this new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382473/php-why-do-it-echo-array there's my new updated code also