# Why does this PHP code just echo "Array"?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['check']) AND $_POST['check'] == 'First') {
  $errormessage = array();

  if(empty($_POST['full_name']) || strlen($_POST['full_name']) < 4) { 
     $errormessage[] = "FEL - Vänligen ange fullständiga namn. Please enter atleast 3 or more characters for your name";
  }
  if(!isEmail($_POST['usr_email'])) {
     $errormessage[] = "FEL - Invalid email address.";
  }
  if(empty($errormessage)) {
     echo 1;
  } else { 
     echo $errormessage; // <--
  }
}
```

When `echo $errormessage` runs it outputs `Array`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are calling `echo` on an actual array, which does not have an implicit string representation.

In order to output an array's contents you can use the `print_r`, `var_dump` or `var_export` functions or for custom output, you can use `array_map` or even a `foreach` loop:

```
print_r($errormessage);
var_dump($errormessage);
var_export($errormessage);

foreach($errormessage as $error) 
   echo $error . '<br/>';

array_map('echo', $errormessage);
```

Comment: Or `var_dump` or if you want to have the array code `var_export`.

Comment: Uuuum, no. `echo` cannot be used as a callback -- it isn't a function. https://3v4l.org/oT6s0

Answer (score 7):

`$errormessage` is an array and using `echo` on an array prints just `Array`.

If you want to print your error messages in a decent way, you can either use `foreach` to iterate the messages and print each message:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($errormessage as $message) {
    echo '<li>'.htmlspecialchars($message).'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Or you can even use some advanced array processing like [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) to do something like this that is equivalent to the previously shown when the array contains at least one item:

```
echo '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', array_map('htmlspecialchars', $errormessage)) . '</li></ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pretty-print the array.  How you do this is up to you.

If you're passing the array to some JavaScript, you probably want to encode it as a JSON array:

```
echo json_encode($errormessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$errormessage = array();
$errormessage[] = "...";
```

Both defines $errormessage as array datatype. Echo prints data from string or numeric format. To print data from array either use print_r as suggested or loop through the members of array and use echo

Answer (score 0):

To see what's inside you variable just do

```
   print_r( $errormessage );
   // or
   var_dump( $errormessage );
```

Answer (score -1):

use the code as like this

```
if(isset($_POST['check']) AND $_POST['check'] == 'First') {
$errormessage = array();
 if(empty($_POST['full_name']) || strlen($_POST['full_name']) < 4)
 {
 $errormessage['error_what_ever_key_you_want'] = "FEL - Vänligen ange fullständiga namn. Please enter atleast 3 or more   characters for your name";
 }
 if(!isEmail($_POST['usr_email'])) {
 $errormessage['error_what_ever_key_you_want'] = "FEL - Invalid email address.";
 }
if(!empty($errormessage)){
echo $errormessage['error_what_ever_key_you_want']; // <--
}
}
```